# How to render bootstrap modal with nested remote content

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table API to create a table from json url. This is mentioned in http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#show-columns-table

I have a requirement where I load the content onto modal from server. The server returns the similar kind of code in the below example:

`<table data-url="data3.json" data-height="299" data-show-columns="true" data-id-field="id">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name" data-switchable="false">Name</th>
        <th data-field="price">Price</th>
        <th data-field="column1">Columns1</th>
        <th data-field="column2" data-visible="false">Columns2</th>
        <th data-field="column3" data-switchable="false">Columns3</th>
        <th data-field="column4" data-visible="false">Columns4</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>`

How do I direct bootstrap to render the content in modal so that I have the table?